# After adding @PathVariable, resources become unreachable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
    @GetMapping("/instructor-edit-course")
    private String instructorAddCourse(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("course", new Course());

        return "instructor-edit-course";
    }
```

Above code is ok. Resources are found.
But when I add @PathVariable to the path like below code, application searches resources in

http://localhost:8080/**instructor-edit-course**/assets/images/icon/footer/facebook-square@2x.png

instead of

http://localhost:8080/assets/images/icon/footer/facebook-square@2x.png

```
@GetMapping("/instructor-edit-course/{id}")
    private String instructorEditCourse(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        // go to course page
        Course course = courseService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
        model.addAttribute("course", course);

        return "instructor-edit-course";
    }
```

**WebConfig class**

```
package com.hrglob.elearning.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxxx.*"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/public", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/static/assets/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        var templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(0);

        return templateResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        var templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        var viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: You specified `/instructor-edit-course/{id}` as path. so the ID will be appended to `instructor-edit-course`. If you don't want the application to behave this way, you have to change the path in @GetMapping to `/{id}`. I don't really understand your problem to be honest. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added ResourceHandler to WebConfig to ensure where the resources are read from. But when I use pathVariable, spring ignores it and starts to read resources from request mapping's path. Why?